# Set the timeout for a message in ActiveMQ broker?

Tags: activemq-classic, broker

I want to set the timeout period for the Acknowledge i.e. if the acknowledge is not received by the broker for the particular message from consumer within a time period then, the broker should resend the message to the consumer. Is it possible to set such settings in the broker???

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple links that explain how to solve this problem with ActiveMQ 5.9:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3394
- https://planet.jboss.org/post/coming_in_activemq_5_9_a_new_way_to_abort_slow_consumers

To summarize:

- if the consumer JVM dies, the JMS connection between broker and consumer will timeout, and any unacknowledged message will be re-scheduled for delivery
- if the JMS connection doesn't die but the consumer is stuck processing a message, [`AbortSlowAckConsumerStrategy`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.9.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/policy/AbortSlowAckConsumerStrategy.html) will abort slow consumers when they reach the configured threshold of slowness, default is that a consumer that has not Ack'd a message for 30 seconds is slow

Answer (score 1):

see http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Acknowledgement-Timeout-td4531016.html

> There is no support for this with the redelivery policy. jms is
>   connection oriented, so the assumption is that if the connection is
>   alive and there is no ack, the consumer has a good reason not to ack
>   yet.